# How to configure mirror node in OPENLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have two OpenLDAP servers : x.x.x.x:389 and y.y.y.y:389.

My `slapd.conf` for the first server :

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema

pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

modulepath      /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload      back_mdb.la
moduleload      back_ldap.la
moduleload      syncprov.la

database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824
suffix          "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootpw          ******

directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq

overlay syncprov

#Global section 
serverID 1


syncrepl rid=001
                 provider=ldap://y.y.y.y:389
                 binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 bindmethod=simple
                 credentials=****
                 searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 type=refreshAndPersist
                 interval=00:00:00:05
                 retry="5 5 300 5"
                 timeout=1

mirrormode on
```

`sldap.conf` for the second server :

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema

pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

modulepath      /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload      back_mdb.la
moduleload      back_ldap.la
moduleload      syncprov.la

database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824
suffix          "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootpw          ****

directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq

overlay syncprov

#Global section
serverID   2
#database section

syncrepl rid=001
                 provider=ldap://x.x.x.x:389
                 binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 bindmethod=simple
                 credentials=****
                 searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 type=refreshAndPersist
                 interval=00:00:00:05
                 retry="5 5 300 5"
                 timeout=1

mirrormode on
```

Both servers are running, but one server tries to fetch entry but doesn't replicate any data.
Anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You need to look in the log file, enabling a debug level if necessary. There are many possibilities, starting with the slave not being able to login or access what it needs to access. See the extensive documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple of things, and it works now.  I am sharing my conf file here.

`slapd.conf` for the first server

```
modulepath      /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload      back_mdb.la
moduleload      back_ldap.la
moduleload      syncprov.la

database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824
suffix          "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootpw          ******

directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq

overlay syncprov

#Global section 
serverid 1                       // I changed serverID 1 to serverid 1 


syncrepl rid=001
                 provider=ldap://y.y.y.y:389
                 binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 bindmethod=simple
                 credentials=****
                 searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 type=refreshAndPersist
                 interval=00:00:00:05
                 retry="5 5 300 5"
                 timeout=1

syncrepl rid=002                                          // added this
         provider=ldap://x.x.x.x:389
         binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
         bindmethod=simple
         credentials=secret
         searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
         schemachecking=on
         type=refreshAndPersist
         interval=00:00:00:05
         retry="60 +"


mirrormode TRUE                         // I changed on to TRUE
```

`slapd.conf` for the second server

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema

pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

modulepath      /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload      back_mdb.la
moduleload      back_ldap.la
moduleload      syncprov.la

database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824
suffix          "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootpw          ****

directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq

overlay syncprov

#Global section
serverid   2                                    //serverID --> serverid
#database section

syncrepl rid=001
                 provider=ldap://y.y.y.y:389
                 binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 bindmethod=simple
                 credentials=****
                 searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
                 type=refreshAndPersist
                 interval=00:00:00:05
                 retry="5 5 300 5"
                 timeout=1

syncrepl rid=002                               //added this
         provider=ldap://x.x.x.x:389
         binddn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
         bindmethod=simple
         credentials=secret
         searchbase="dc=my-domain,dc=com"
         schemachecking=on
         type=refreshAndPersist
         interval=00:00:00:05
         retry="60 +"


mirrormode TRUE                        //  on  -->  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi, did you config standard replication before these configuration?

Comment: @khodekazemi  This was done long long time ago. And now I don't do LDAP. Hope this helps. :) https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html